# Javascript parameter inside string not recognized

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For Firebase Cloudfunctions I am trying to update a value based on a dynmaic ID.
This ID is saved inside a const value. The exact field I try to reach via dot-notation.
Here is my complete function:

```
exports.badgeUpdated = functions.firestore
    .document("badges/{docId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, context ) => {
      //  get the document that has changed and the new fieldvalue
      const ObjectId = change.after.id;
      const newObject = change.after.data();
      const newBadgeName = newObject.badgeName;
      //  const newImageUrl = newObject.badgeImageUrl;
      console.log(`New BadgeName ${newBadgeName}`);
      console.log(`New BadgeID ${ObjectId}`);
      //  Search badge doc with changed ID and set new name
      const querySnapshot = await admin
          .firestore()
          .collectionGroup("keekzCards")
          .where("badgeContains", "array-contains", ObjectId).get();
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        doc.ref.update({"badges.${ObjectId}.badgeName": newBadgeName});
        console.log(doc.id);
      });
      // console.log(`Queryresult ${(querySnapshot).docs}`);
      return null;
    });
```

The code itself is working, however instead of updating the field the function is creating an individual map-field using the plain string instead of resolving the underlying constant value. So after running the function my firestore document is looking like so:

[image]

EDIT:
When exchaning the quotes the following error appears:
[image]

Comment: You used a regular string `"` instead of a template string `\`` it's just a typo.

Comment: I was thinking the same, however when I exchange the characters I am receiving this error (see edit in original post)

Comment: You can't use a template string in an object literal declaration. Store it in a var and use the computed property notation: `const foo = \`whatever\`; const bar = { [foo]: 'something' };`

Comment: Or use bracket notation: `doc.ref.update({badges[ObjectId].badgeName: newBadgeName});`

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectId` is a reserved keyword. Avoid using it. Use instead `objectId` or `oId`:

```js
const objectId = change.after.id;
```